# Windows 10 start menu CTD

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I can open my start menu just fine, but if I don't select something within 5 seconds or if I type out a search query it immediately freezes for 3 seconds then basically does a CTD.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What is a CTD? ...

Comment: Run [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) and let us know if it finds anything.

Comment: @DavidPostill it means crash to desktop. What I meant is it exhibits the same behaviour as when a game crashes to desktop. It freezes and then completely exits. You're then caught looking at your desktop wondering where your game went. Same thing here. Only difference is, I can still hit the windows menu key and it comes up again, but the same thing happens.

Comment: @harrymc I'm doing that right now. 51% complete.

Comment: @harrymc corruption was found. I have the CBS.log file if you want to read through it cause I can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: Please post the log and I'll have a look.

Comment: @harrymc [log & sfcdetails](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cOto_twLfjDGo8IDRCDB81xkmR-yNp8W)
That's the log
[This is what's happening](https://imgur.com/a/7K3nNd8)

Comment: @Chamkey you should include the full log in your question. This will help if others are having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the logs you posted, it seems that there is a permission problem on some key
Windows folders. This is usually symptomatic of having taken ownership of these
folders in order to force-do some Windows changes.

First try doing `chkdsk` to check for disk corruption. If errors are found,
fix them with `chkdsk /f`.

If this does not help with `sfc /scannow`,
the only solution which might avoid a clean install of Windows is to try doing
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
Create a boot media with the latest Windows 10 version, as described in the link,
and run it from inside Windows.

If this fails, you might be required to install Windows from scratch.

In all cases, take good backups before starting any of the above steps.

Comment: had to do a repair install.